# How to start Tracking location in shedule UWP?

Tags: android, uwp

How to tracking location in schedule?

**Example:**

Auto turn on tracking location from 7AM and finish at 11AM
Auto turn on tracking location from 13:00 and finish at 17:00

Please explain in code because my ENGLISH is very bad!

Comment: what is your intention to tag `uwp` and `android`?

Comment: I'm learning to develop android and UWP platform, please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Auto turn on tracking location from 7AM and finish at 11AM
>    Auto turn on tracking location from 13:00 and finish at 17:00

In order to implement your requirement, first we need to know how to implement the location tracing, in UWP we can use the [geofence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/set-up-a-geofence) with the Backgroundtask to handle the location tracing.
For more information, please check [this official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Geolocation).
Besides, you may meet some problema during using the [geofence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/set-up-a-geofence) with the Backgroundtask, if so, please check my reply in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36161960/backgroundtask-geofence-triggering).

After that we may need to know how to implement auto tracking from the shedule time. We can implement the time check inside the run method of the Backgroundtask, if the current time is not the schedule time, we will not execute the special operation for the location tracing.

Comment: My job make my move a lot, so I need an app can auto tracking my location in work-hour (Morning: 7:00:00 - 11:00:00 and Noon: 13:00:00 - 17:00:00) I only use location tracking to calculate distance i moved with Kilometer unit and save it to database via SQLite. Now my app work fine with ExtendedExecution with location reason, but I must start tracking by hand. If you have a best way to tracking location and do it in schedule, please suggest me. THANK YOU!

Comment: And Schedule time can input from TextBox

Comment: As I have said in my first reply, if we want to do it in schedule, we can implement the time check inside the run method of the Backgroundtask, if the current time is not the schedule time, we will not execute the special operation for the location tracing. You can also use the TimeTrigger to help do the time check.